# My vagrant was working perfectly fine last night. I've just turned the PC on, hit vagrant reload, and this is what I get:

Tags: vagrant, hyper-v

```
vagrant reload
 default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
    default: Guest communication could not be established! This is usually because
    default: SSH is not running, the authentication information was changed,
    default: or some other networking issue. Vagrant will force halt, if
    default: capable.
 default: Stopping the machine...
 default: Starting the machine...
 default: Waiting for the machine to report its IP address...
    default: Timeout: 120 seconds
    default: IP: 172.18.128.108
 default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 172.18.128.108:22
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
```

Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.

```
C:\>vagrant reload
```

There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

Hyper-V:
* The following settings shouldn't exist: gui

Comment: Is your vagrant remote, or there is a way to have gui access?

Comment: On Virtual Box I would connect directly to the machine, to check error messages. Would this be a way, also for Hyper-V? (I've got Win Pro, but still use Virtual Box, which unfortunately does not work anymore, when Hyper-V is enabled)

Comment: Sorry my vagrant stands in the company but also the solution brings me no further

Comment: I can give you my file